# Regular expression Rewrite rule

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am struggling with a mod rewrite regular expression that extracts the language from the URL and transforms it into an http parameter.

I want to rewrite
`mydomain/FR/workingdays_per_month_2015.htm` into
`mydomain/tables.php?annnecal=2015&language=FR`

and

`mydomain/ES/workingdays_per_month_2016.htm` into `mydomain/tables.php?annnecal=2016&language=ES`

The following rule works:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]{2,2})/workingdays_per_month_([0-9]*).htm tables.php?anneecal=$2&language=$1  [L]
```

If the language is omitted in the url, I want to rewrite to default language (english):
`mydomain/workingdays_per_month_2015.htm` into `mydomain/tables.php?annnecal=2015&language=EN`

so I added this rule:

```
 RewriteRule ^workingdays_per_month_([0-9]*).htm tables.php?anneecal=$1&language=EN  [L]
```

Those two rules works separately but not together.

If I visit `mydomain/workingdays_per_month_2015.htm`
I get a 404 (not found) for this page (when the two rules are added one after another in the .htacess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was actually coming from my Notepad++ editor running on windows and my web server running on Unix.

My end of lines were [LF].

My Unix server, expecting EOL as [CR][LF], was thus seeing just one rule, not two.

In Notepad++, 
using **View | Show symbol | Show end of line**
and 
**Edit | EOL Conversion | Unix**

solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([A-Z]{2})/workingdays_per_month_([0-9]+)\.htm$ tables.php?anneecal=$2&language=$1  [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^workingdays_per_month_([0-9]+)\.htm$ tables.php?anneecal=$1&language=EN  [L,QSA,NC]
```

Make sure these rules are placed before your other rules.

Comment: Would you like to provide more details about it here.